# How to pass parameters to Jenkins' API with Python and api4jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api, api4jenkins

I'm having trouble with Jenkins' API while using Python *3.10.2* with Ubuntu LTS *20.4* with Jenkins *2.361* with api4jenkins *1.11* as the wrapper for the API.

My main trouble is passing parameters to a Task. I'm able to start the task, and I'm doing as the [examples](https://api4jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/example.html#jenkins) indicate to pass the parameters, but the taks' execution don't print the parameters.

Jenkins has a global security configuration for each user, this is the one for the user that's starting the task:

[image: Jenkins Global Security Configuration]

My Task is called ***Prueba4***, the task security configuration is this one:

[image: Prueba4 security configuration]

Right now, I only have the parameter *client*:

[image: Prueba4 parameters]

I also enabled script execution:

[image: Script execution]

The only step is this shell command:

```
echo Hello
echo $USER
echo $cliente
```

With Python I'm doing this:

```
from api4jenkins import Jenkins
j = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080/', auth=('my_user', 'mypass'))

j.build_job('Prueba4', client="my cliente", token="my_token", delay='1sec')
```

So I can't find the problem that the line echo $client does not show the parameter I passed. Adding print to api4jenkins I was able to identify that it pass this kwards:

```
method: POST
url +: http://localhost:8080/job/Prueba4/buildWithParameters
kwards: {'params': {'client': 'my_client'}, 'token': 'my_token', 'delay': '1sec'}, 'headers': {'Jenkins-Crumb': '81bec758701d0783a68f3ad4050e42c647953834f1c552120b194d6e8b989f52'}}
```

I don't know what I' doing wrong. This is an execution started with python that doesn't print the parameter:

[image: Python execution]

I tried with CURL and Python's Request library, but I'm not able to make a request with them yet.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

**EDIT:** Ok, I was making a dumb mistake, I really needed to pass a dictionary and I was adding the variable directly, I forgot to send it as a string, the  true reason why Jenkins was not accepting the request.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I forgot to search in the issues pages in the Github page from api4jenkins, there i found [this issue](https://github.com/joelee2012/api4jenkins/issues/31). In there Sinutok commented on 7 Sep 2021 the solution:

> Sorry wasted your time....got it facepalm I'll post my now running
> code as example, if someone needs it

```
jenkins_server = api4jenkins.Jenkins('https://myjenkins.example.com:8443', auth=('someuser','the_api_token'),verify=False)
user = jenkins_server.me.exists()
version = jenkins_server.version
print(str(user))
print(str(version))
job = jenkins_server.get_job("API-TEST - JOB")
print(job)
lauf = job.build(TEXT1="C",TEXT2="lalala")
print(lauf)

Output:
True
2.277.4
<FreeStyleProject: https://myjenkins.example.com:8443/job/API-TEST%20-%20JOB/>
<QueueItem: https://myjenkins.example.com:8443/queue/item/1149/>
```

> ```
> and the jenkis job runs correctly with the Parameters: "C" (of the dropdown-box) and "lalala" (of the text-in-field)
> ```

EDIT: Ok, I was making a dumb mistake, I really needed to pass a dictionary and I was adding the variable directly, I forgot to send it as a string, the true reason why Jenkins was not accepting the request. This issue help me see it.